# В чём разница в смысле между «зря не прислал» и «надо было прислать»?

Tags: значение-слов

> Я же говорил, **зря** он **не** **прислал** Алису.
>
> Я же говорил, **надо было прислать** Алису.

Оставляя в стороне вопрос о том, включить ли местоимение «он/ему» или нет, ощущается ли какая-то разница?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Между исходными выражениями "зря не прислал" и "надо было прислать" некоторая разница есть: в первом выражении подразумевается, что разговор об этом был (выражение звучит как *упрёк* или сожаление с оттенком "соболезнования" не приславшему), во втором - этого нет (больше похоже на анализ результатов - как следовало действовать; возможно, ещё не поздно это изменить). Однако добавление фразы "**я же говорил**" практически полностью нивелирует смысловую разницу: в обоих случаях звучит упрёк, что говорящего в своё время не послушали.

Comment: @ Alex_ander, полностью согласен с вашим ответом. Но насчет "соболезнования", по-моему, вы немного преувеличили.

Comment: Я имею в виду случай, когда "прислание Алисы" было в интересах того, кто мог её прислать.

Comment: Да, это понятно. Но при чем тут соболезнование?

Comment: Он мог и большие деньги потерять, но я этим словом просто обозначил направленность сожаления. Поставлю его в кавычки на всякий случай.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, так будет яснее.

Answer (score 1):

Вар. 1. *Я же говорил, зря он не прислал Алису.*

*Он* (третье лицо), возможно,  собирался ее прислать, но передумал.

Вар.2 *Я же говорил, надо было прислать Алису.*

О *нем* речи нет, но собеседники говорили на эту тему раньше,  тогда и предлагалось прислать Алису.

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае - выражение может быть префразировано как "плохо, что не прислал Алису". Основной акцент - на глаголе (прислали / не прислали).

Во втором случае, помимо более нейтрального смысла, акцент может быть не только на слове "надо" (надо было прислать, но не прислал), а также на глаголе:

***Надо было прислать Алису, а не задерживать / телепортировать / привозить.***

Либо на объекте:

***Надо было прислать именно Алису, а не Вертера / Громозеку / профессора Селезнёва.***

В первом случае вариативность интерпретации тоже возможна, но менее очевидна и достигается главным образом интонационными модуляциями.

Также следует отметить, что оборот "зря (не) ... может использоваться во всех временах как с глаголами совершенного, так и несовершенного вида, а оборот "надо было" - только в прошедшем и с глаголами совершенного.

(Странно, что никто не заметил одной небольшой неточности: "прислать" больше употребимо для неодушевлённого объекта).

Comment: @ Manjusri,вы ошибаетесь. Глагол "прислать" употребляется и по отношению к одушевленным предметам. См.: Большой толковый словарь на Грамоте.ру.

Comment: @Manjusri По поводу неточности: **Прислать** 2. кого (что). Направить куда-н. с какой-н. целью. _Прислать помощника._ https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/184206#